# Find all primitive roots modulo $18.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, primitive-roots

- Find all primitive roots modulo $18.$

My Attempt. I need to show $ord_{18} (a)=\phi(18)=5.$

$5^4=13 \bmod 18$, I couldn't find primitve root mod $18$, can you help? Can you add an answer? Thanks...

Comment: $\phi(18)=6, $ not $5$ [$\phi(18)=\phi(2)\phi(9)=\phi(9)=6$]

Comment: $18$ is a very small number.  Just check each class separately if you really can't think of anything better.  Note:  $\varphi(18)=6$, not $5$.  For $n>2$ we must have $\varphi(n)$ even.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner $\phi(18):\left\{17,13,11,7,5\right\}$, right? The set has $5$ elements, not $6$?

Comment: You left off $1$.

Comment: @lulu $1$ and $18$, relatively prime?

Comment: yes, $\gcd(1,18)=1$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Ahh yess! I understood! Thanks :)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner There is no primitive root mod 18, right?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I'm false. There exist but  I couldn't find myself, can you add an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The multiplicative group of invertible elements modulo $18$, $(\mathbb Z/18\mathbb Z)^\ast,$

has $\phi(18)=\phi(2)\phi(9)=\phi(9)=6$ elements:  $\{1,5,7,11,13,17\}$.

The order of $1$ is $1$, the order of $17$ is $2$, the order of $7$ and its inverse $13$ is $3$,

and the order of $5$ and its inverse $11$ is $6$.

So the primitive roots mod $18$ are $5$ and $11$.

Comment: $(\mathbb Z/18\mathbb Z)^\ast$ is a cyclic group of order $6$ so has $\phi(6)=2$ generators

Comment: Thanks for answer and helping...